# Execute Javascript on a Website via script

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

**Hello!**

So, when I open a Website in Chrome and press F12 I can open up the console and type in commands. I want to do the same via a script, maybe something like Node.js. I want go to any Website I want and execute console commands in my script.

Is that possible? Is there an API I have to use?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for  page automation, if you are familiar with javascript you can use PhantomJS. Take a look at page automation using PhantomJS [here](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html).

If you want to go with progamming languages like Java,C#,python,etc you can use Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

check [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). you can evaluate script in the context of the page